# How do I avoid accidentally stealing things?

Tags: baldurs-gate-3

While wandering around town I accidentally clicked on a chest. This led to me getting arrested for stealing and sent to jail. Is there an option to prevent stealing so one accidental misclick doesn't get me sent to jail?

Comment: Other than "save early, save often"?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Illegal actions are shown by a red icon when you hover with the cursor, and as red colored text options in the context menu.

You are adviced to take care what you click on, you will run into more situations where clicking without being careful will lead to nasty situations >:)