# How do I increase the autosave frequency?

Tags: baldurs-gate-3

I [made a mistake in Baldur's Gate 3](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/q/404000/181240) and decided to reload my last save. To my dismay, my last autosave was from over an hour ago. How do I increase how often the game autosaves?

Comment: When you're loading a save, you can see how much playtime is on that save and when the save was made, to avoid things like this

Answer (score 17, accepted):

There is no way to do this, as it only autosaves before specific events. If you are wandering, you could easily go hours without a save.

Instead, you should get used to hitting F5 to Quick Save and F8 to Quick Load.

[image: Baldur's Gate 3]

Comment: I like games that have this feature tbh. Because often games crash on my PC, and relying on a spotty or infrequent auto save tends to make me lose progress a lot when a game crashes.

Comment: just make sure you never hit the wrong one by accident, like something bad happens, want to reload, save instead :-) frequent quicksave only makes sense if the quicksave slot's versioned, i.e. you cannot overwrite existing saves

Comment: @Haukinger Or worse, you complete a tricky battle or puzzle, go to save, and accidentally load a save from an hour before!

Comment: Or get a macro keyboard with those keys and set it to auto save and auto reload :D

Comment: To avoid bad quicksaves, one can locate the file, and make a macro that copies it as backup. (E.g. [AutoHotkey](https://www.autohotkey.com/), remap F5 to both send F5 and make a backup)

Comment: @Haukinger Afaik you can configure BG3 to rotate through any number of quicksave slots. Even if you accidentally hit save instead of load, you can still manually go back to the n-1 save. It's like the game is designed around save scumming ;)